# Lyapunov-Schmidt reduction.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-function-theorem, bifurcation

> Use Lyapunov-Schmidt reduction to find an expression, or
>   approximation, of the set of equilibria, as a function of the
>   parameter $\lambda$, of the planar vector field
>   $$f(x,y,\lambda)=(\lambda + 2x + y - x^2, 2x + (1+\lambda)y - xy)$$
>   near the equilibrium $(x,y) = (0,0)$ at $\lambda = 0$.

So, usually, we tackle this problem by using the Implicit Function Theorem twice. Firstly, we define
$f_1(x,y,\lambda) = \lambda + 2x + y - x^2, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $
$f_2(x,y,\lambda) =2x + (1+\lambda)y - xy$.

Since $f_1(0,0,0) = 0$ and $D_x f_1(0,0,0)=2$, so it's invertible, the implicit function theorem states that there exist open neighborhoods $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ of $0$ and a function $x^*: V \to U$ such that $f_1(x,y,\lambda) = 0 \iff x^*(y,\lambda) = x$, with $x^*(0,0) = 0$. Furthermore, $D_y x^*(0,0) = -(D_x f_1 (0,0,0))^{-1} D_y f_1 (0,0,0) = -(2)^{-1}1 = -\tfrac{1}{2}$.

Now, we substitute $x^*(y,\lambda)$ for $x$ in $f_2$, and again we want to apply the IFT to express $y$ in terms of $\lambda$. So we define $g(y,\lambda) = f_2(x^*(y,\lambda), y, 
\lambda) = 2x^*(y,\lambda) + (1+\lambda)y - x^*(y,\lambda)y$. However, $D_y g(0,0) = 2D_y x^*(0,0) + 1 + 0 - D_y x^*(0,0)\cdot 0 -x^*(0,0)  =0$, so we can't apply the IFT.

Is this just an ill-chosen example, or is there a different approach possible?

Comment: In short, LS is set up precisely for this scenario. Had the imp fun thm worked on the second equation you wouldn't need LS since you could have used imp fun thm for the full map $f$. If you carry the Taylor approximation of your $g$ out to higher order, you will see whether or not you can solve the equation based on the quadratic terms.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Over the equilibrium set we have

$$
\lambda+2x+y-x^2= 0\\
2x+(1+\lambda)y-xy = 0
$$

so after eliminating $\lambda$

$$
y^2-\left(x^2-3 x+1\right) y-2 x=0
$$

and we have two leafs as can be observed in the plot below

$$
y =  \frac{1}{2} \left((x-3) x\pm\sqrt{x^4-6 x^3+11 x^2+2 x+1}+1\right)
$$

[image]